# How can I download an embedded video from Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, video

I have macOS 10.15.7 and Safari 14.0.

I would like to download some webinars that I would like to access offline. They are embedded in the website but I am not sure if they are Flash videos or HTML5 or what.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Almost no-one uses Flash any more. Right click it, see what options you get. If they don't want you to download it, the option will not be available.

Comment: This procedure will not work for copyright protected video, but if you go into the Sources tab of the inspector you can peruse for the video file. If you right click the video file and copy link, this *may* work. DRM protections do not allow this to work, so if this doesn't work you won't be able to download the video file directly.

Comment: You can try using `youtube-dl` command line tool to see if you can download the video.

Comment: @EzekielElin it worked. Just open the Inspector (Alt+Cmd+I) and search for the tab Networks. If the video has been played, it will appear a URL from which you can download it. Thanks!